hypersistence-utils: Way to implement custom Postgres type
I am interested to use the acl add-on for Postgres (see text.
This code uses a custom type, named ace, for efficient storage.
For each table, a column ace[] is defined.
Is it possible to extend hypersistence-utils: with a type for ace[] and are there some directions how to do so?
Thanks,
-- Jaap
I've looked into the source code of hypersistence-utils, and AbstractArrayType seems to be the starting point.
